# Can destructuring cause bugs in future?

Tags: scala, destructuring

Initialy we have a code like

```
class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String)

val (firstName, lastName) = person
```

Somebody swaps fields

```
class Person(lastName: String, firstName: String)

val (firstName, lastName) = person
```

Compiler is happy!

Comment: look both parameters have same type String, if you pass string in both parameters, compiler don't check that is Fname or Lname, it just check params types. so issue with you not compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler has no way to know you swapped the order of the fields because the analysis doesn't look up the argument *name*. As long as the typer type checks, everything is fine. What you can do is an additional level of types:

```
case class FirstName(name: String)
case class LastName(name: String)

class Person(firstName: FirstName, lastName: LastName)
```

Now swapping the types will cause a compile time error.

If you don't want the additional overhead of allocationing additional objects, look into [shapeless tagged types](http://www.vlachjosef.com/tagged-types-introduction/):

```
import shapeless.tag.@@

trait FirstNameTag
trait LastNameTag

type FirstName = String @@ FirstNameTag
type LastName = String @@ LastNameTag

case class Person(fn: FirstName, ln: LastName)
```

And now:

```
import shapeless.tag

val firstName: FirstName = tag[FirstNameTag][String]("yuv")
val lastName: LastName = tag[LastName][String]("itz")

val person = Person(firstName, lastName)
```

or as @Ren points out use [value classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html):

```
case class FirstName(name: String) extends AnyVal
case class LastName(name: String) extends AnyVal
```

Comment: There's also the "extends AnyVal" option for avoiding overhead - http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html

Comment: @Ren Definitely! Added to the answer

Comment: @Ren value classes can work but they are limited in what you can do with them before they create an extra object.  The worst part is they will be silently initialized giving you a performance hit when you think they are not.  I don't know about tagged types of if they avoid these problems but if they do they are a much better option than AnyVal

Comment: @puhlen The point of tagged types is to reduce allocations, so I think they're on par in that regards. I agree in regards to `AnyVal`, but one is general should be familiar with the caveats they entail before using them. I'll add that to the answer as well.